# Object's members' values change as soon as interrupt is fired

Tags: c++, embedded

I have a UART class that has instances of `Fifo`. What I notice is as soon as the UART IRQ handler is fired, the member variables of `Fifo` instance change. I can't think of putting breakpoint any further because things seem perfectly fine inside `Uart::init()`...and the next thing to happen is the IRQ handler.

```c
// uart.hpp
class Uart 
{
  Fifo rx;
  Fifo tx;
  public:
  void init();
  void irqHandler();
};

// uart.cpp
static Uart *pUart;

void Uart::init() 
{
  pUart = this;
  // verified Uart::rx's members are as expected
  // ...
}

void IRQ_Handler(void) 
{
  pUart->irqHandler();
}

void Uart::irqHandler() 
{
    // Uart::rx members seem to have changed here...
}

int main(void) 
{
  Uart uart;
  uart.init();
  while(1);
}
```

Comment: when I added a couple additional lines (`int a; a++;`) inside `IRQ_Handler`, I don't see this issue of `Uart::rx` members changing.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to debug optimised code?

Comment: what did you mean by an optimised code?

Comment: did you use the compiler optimisation switch in the build of this code?  Generally it is better to use no compiler optimisation when using a symbolic debugger.

Comment: `pUart` should in any event be `static volatile Uart*`. "How to Use C’s Volatile Keyword" https://barrgroup.com/embedded-systems/how-to/c-volatile-keyword

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare shared objects to be volatile:

```
static volatile Uart *pUart;
```

2. Do not expect the debugger session to be easy to comprehend if the code has been compiled with optimisation switches.  Code and data can be omitted or reordered such that it no longer reflects the sequence or state implied by the source code.

Comment: so your suspicion is uart instance's members are getting optimized during the ISR execution? what would cause the members to change their values? `volatile` is used to force the compiler to read the value off the register

Comment: @Jazzy Optimisation occurs during compilation statically, not during execution. The members need not change value, it may be that the pointer is not loaded and simply refers to different memory.  I would not want to second guess the optimiser or try to figure out how it works. Did you follow the link? Volatile is not just for registers. It is for memory shared between thread contexts too.  The compiler can assume that the ISR is not used because nothing in the main thread calls it, that can lead to all sorts of erroneous optimisation that you need to prevent.

Comment: Yes I've peeked at this link before. Isn't the ISR invoked regardless though? and by ISR, i'm referring to `IRQ_Handler`. You may be implying `pUart->irqHandler()` which may not get invoked because compiler may optimize `pUart`?

Comment: @Jazzy Threads and interrupts are not part of the C language. The the compiler is not aware of interrupts or how, when or even if they will be invoked if there is no explicit call. That is a hardware function. You could second guess this answer or you could try it. If it does not solve the problem, then there is something further to investigate. If you need to know why it works, that is better dealt with in a new question.

Comment: Another concern might be that the `IRQ_Handler` isn't even regarded as an ISR by the compiler. And then the compiler notes that it isn't getting called. Even if you managed to register the function in the vector table. Most compilers want some non-standard thing there, such as `interrupt` or `__attribute(blahblah)__`  or some pragma.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, though often the effect of such extensions is simply to create a function with RTI rather than RET return instruction.  Not all architectures (ARM Cortex-M for example) require that.  In other cases, the true interrupt handler entry is elsewhere (in assembly code), and that assembly wrapper invokes a C coded handler, avoiding the need for compiler directives or extensions.  From the question context in this case I assume the handler is however being invoked, so has been linked.

Comment: @Clifford Not only the RTI, but also to generate code for stacking necessary parts that aren't stacked by hardware upon interrupt invocation. It's fairly common that some cores only stack a few registers and then expect the ISR to stack others. This can be different from a regular function call's calling convention.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, all that may happen.  What I meant was that it may not specifically affect linkage, but clearly you'd expect a function declared as an interrupt handler to be linked, so my point was probably irrelevant.   Your advice on platform/toolchain specific interrupt handler support should be heeded.

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with stack overflow possibly than not using `volatile`. My problem with `volatile` is the `pInstance` isn't changing anywhere neither what it points to is till the IRQ is fired. As soon as the IRQ is fired, all the members seem to look OK except for `Fifo` instances.If I were modifying a variable in an IRQ and reading it off elsewhere then it would make more sense to use volatile I think. Plus, using `volatile` like you mentioned errors out `error: passing 'volatile Uart' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @Jazzy none of the code fragment you have included would cause anyone to suspect a stack of.  We can only comment on the evidence presented, but it seems you have answered your own question.